# camera to object distance calculation using opencv and python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, distance

I am using Microsoft Lifecam HD 3000 on my quadcopter for autonomous landing .
I wish to calculate the distance between the onboard camera on the quadcopter and a landing pad which has a rectangle printed on it. The distance can then be fed as error to the PID controller. i am using python to code this. Could anyone suggest a simple way to find the distance.

PS: I don't need the exact value of distance

Answer (score 2):

If the landing rectangle size is known/constant then it is doable

1. **some data to prepare**

   Take image of the landing rectangle at known distance. Use your **Microsoft Lifecam HD 3000** with the same setup as on the copter (or take it by itself) and compute/measure the rectangle size in pixels and store it. So you have:

   - `xs0,ys0` - rectangle size [px]
   - `d0` - distance from camera image was taken [m]
2. **take the image**

   Find the rectangle on it and try to project it as it was taken perpendicular to camera view axis. Then compute its size in pixels `xs,ys`
3. **compute the distance**

   Use the triangle similarity

   [image: FOV example]

   this image was done for this **Q/A**: [Specifiyng speed from visual size](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24245775/2521214) which can be of help. So

   - `h` is the rectangle size in pixels in each axis
   - `z` is the distance from camera focus point

   so rewritten to names above you get

   - `dx=d0*xs/xs0` [m]
   - `dy=d0*ys/ys0` [m]

   `dx` and `dy` should be the same but if your image is not take perpendicular or have other distortions then they will be a bit different. So distance is average of it or min or max depends on safety reasons. For example

   - `d=0.5*(dx+dy)` [m]

**[Notes]**

The distances are measured from projection point of camera so if yo do not know its position take rectangle image from 2 known distances from known point and compute the focus position ...