# Is there a way to find the distance from the hand to camera in Tensorflow handpose model in Javascript?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, object-detection, tensorflow.js, home-automation

Found a great resource to run the TensorFlow Handpose model using React.

The link of the youtube [videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f7uBsb-0sGQ).

The link of the github [repo](https://github.com/nicknochnack/HandPoseDetection).

I want to find the **distance between the camera and hand** to set up a automation system that performs different functions at different lengths between camera and the hand. Unable to crack a solution for it.

Kindly help me find a solution to this.

Comment: You could use [triangle similarity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29249546/camera-to-object-distance-calculation-using-opencv-and-python).