# Estimate the Height from where the image was taken

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, geometry

Say I have the following images:

| Image taken from 40 cm(Say) | Image taken from 25 cm(Say) | Image taken from 15 cm(Say) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] | [image] |

**NOTE :** All the Images will be taken from almost a horizintal camera meaning minimum tilt.

**NOTE :** All the images will be of Grains(Similar to the ones above).

I was looking for some answers on this issue, I dont even know how to begin. **My end goal is to be able to code this for any given image.**

Comment: Will it always be pictures of seeds?

Comment: Yes they will always be seeds. Sorry I should have specified that.

Comment: This tutorial might help. https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/03/28/measuring-size-of-objects-in-an-image-with-opencv/

Comment: Using the method in this link I will only be able to get the size of the object, but how can I extend this to get the distance from where the image was taken?

Comment: Yes, you're right. I suppose you'll have to manually calibrate it first, by plotting a graph with `height` on the x-axis and `pixels_per_metric` of a grain on the y-axis. Interpolating this graph will allow you to deduce the height from the `pixels_per_metric`.

Comment: @MohammedAadil If you know real world size of the object then you can use triangle similarity to compute camera distance to it from the size in pixels ... the angle of triangle is half of the FOV of camera in the axis your size is measured ... The idea os `size1/dist1 = size2/dist2  = tan(FOV/2)` You can also use size in pixels taken from know altitude (distance) instead of the real size ...see related [Specifiyng speed from visual size](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24245776/2521214) look at the FOV frustrum cut image there the `z/h` is your `distance/size` or `altitude/size`

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. I will try both of these methods.